# How to remove repeated values of a pivot table excel?

Tags: excel, formatting, pivot-table

Below is the attached image of a pivot table.

[image: Pivot Table unformatted]

But the values of transaction amount is getting repeated twice.

Intended output:-
[image: Intended output]

How to ensure that Name has a separate column and transaction amount is getting repeated only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the layout to Tabular and turn off subtotals for the Description field.